# Where is the pt field used in the MSG structure?

Tags: c++, winapi

MSG Message Structure:

```
typedef struct tagMSG {
    HWND        hwnd;
    UINT        message;
    WPARAM      wParam;
    LPARAM      lParam;
    DWORD       time;
    POINT       pt;
#ifdef _MAC
    DWORD       lPrivate;
#endif
} MSG, *PMSG, NEAR *NPMSG, FAR *LPMSG;
```

Why is it necessary to store cursor coordinates in a separate field if cursor coordinates are stored in lParam for mouse operation events?

Comment: Perhaps some code might want to use the cursor position for other events as well?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to see an example where this is really useful. Where GetCursorPos is not suitable.

Comment: `GetCursorPos` returns the **current** mouse position. The `pt` field in the `MSG` structure stores the mouse position at the time the message was generated. Those need not be the same. An example of where you might want to know the mouse position: A keyboard interface that operates on the mouse position (e.g. an image processing application that selects the item under the cursor using a keyboard shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the current "global" mouse cursor position might not be the same as the position at the time the message was generated. The threads message queue keeps track of the time and mouse position from the window/threads point of view and simply reports it as part of the data retrieved by `GetMessage`.

This position can also be retried by code that does not have direct access to the `MSG` by calling `GetMessagePos` (and `GetMessageTime`).